# MySQL subquery returns more than one row when using not equal

Tags: mysql

```
mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT category_id,name FROM ek_category_description WHERE category_id <>( SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM ek_category) AND  name LIKE '$searchvalue%'  ")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Change `category_id <>` to `category_id not in (....`

Comment: you should be clarify more that this, you should discuss what is your problem in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use NOT IN

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_id,name 
FROM ek_category_description 
WHERE category_id NOT IN( SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM ek_category) 
AND name LIKE '$searchvalue%'
```

Answer (score 1):

`NOT IN` doesn't tolerate null values so, no result would be given if the result has a null value.
use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_id,name 
FROM ek_category_description 
WHERE category_id NOT EXISTS( SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM ek_category) 
AND name LIKE '$searchvalue%'
```

the `NOT EXISTS` will give results even with null values. 
the `<>` is a singular operator `NOT`, so working with `NOT IN` works better.